# Get current NIC settings

Tags: vb.net, winforms, networking, nic

So, cutting a long story short the section of my code that I am currently unable to figure out is designed to report the current IP settings of a given NIC, so I want it to essentially spit out the IP, Subnet and default Gateway that it is currently set to. I have a solution working but it only seems to play nice when the NIC is set to DHCP which is not good for my application.

Here is my current code:

```
Public Sub NetGet()
    MainForm.NetLabelIP.Text = "IPv4 Address: "
    MainForm.NetLabelIP.Text = "subnet Mask: "
    MainForm.NetLabelIP.Text = "Default Gateway: "

    MainForm.NetLabelCN.Text = "Computer Name: " + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()

    For Each ip In System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
        If ip.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
            'IPv4 Adress
            MainForm.NetLabelIP.Text = "IPv4 Address: " + ip.ToString()

            For Each adapter As Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface In Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                If adapter.Name = MainForm.interfaceSelector.SelectedItem Then
                    For Each unicastIPAddressInformation As Net.NetworkInformation.UnicastIPAddressInformation In adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
                        If unicastIPAddressInformation.Address.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                            If ip.Equals(unicastIPAddressInformation.Address) Then
                                'Subnet Mask
                                MainForm.NetLabelSM.Text = "Subnet Mask: " + unicastIPAddressInformation.IPv4Mask.ToString()

                                Dim adapterProperties As Net.NetworkInformation.IPInterfaceProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties()
                                For Each gateway As Net.NetworkInformation.GatewayIPAddressInformation In adapterProperties.GatewayAddresses
                                    'Default Gateway
                                    MainForm.NetLabelDG.Text = "Default Gateway: " + gateway.Address.ToString()
                                Next

                                If unicastIPAddressInformation.PrefixOrigin = 3 Then
                                    DHCP = True
                                    MainForm.NetLabelDHCP.Text = "DHCP Enabled: TRUE"
                                Else
                                    DHCP = False
                                    MainForm.NetLabelDHCP.Text = "DHCP Enabled: FALSE"
                                End If

                                ''DNS1
                                'if adapterproperties.dnsaddresses.count > 0 then
                                '    label5.text = adapterproperties.dnsaddresses(0).tostring()
                                'end if

                                ''DNS2
                                'if adapterproperties.dnsaddresses.count > 1 then
                                '    label6.text = adapterproperties.dnsaddresses(1).tostring()
                                'end if
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm assuming it's going to be something abhorrently daft in hindsight, however I feel it best to share my request with the community so that anyone else looking for a similar solution can find their answers here.

Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: "Not actually a function I know but idk what else to call it." Just call it a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **`NetInterfacesInfo`** class implements two static (shared) methods the return informations on the Network Interfaces of a Machine:

1. **`NetInterfacesInfo.GetNetworkInterfaces()`**

This method returns all the Network Interfaces that support IPV4 except the Loopback interface.
The informations are returned in a **`List(Of NetWorkInterfacesInfo)`**, which exposes these properties:

- **`ConnectionName`**: The name assigned to the connection (`Local Area Network (LAN)`)
- **`Description`**:  The firendly name of the Interface
- **`IPV4Addresses`**: A simplified list of each Ip Address as string, the associated NetMask and Default Gateway.
- **`IpAddresses`**: A list ot the IP Addresses associated with the Network Interface.
- **`DHCPSservers`**: A list of the DHCP Servers associated with the Network Interface.
- **`DnsServers`**: A list of the DNS Servers associated with the Network Interface.
- **`Gateways`**: A list of Gateways addresses associated with the Network Interface.
- **`IsDHCPEnabled`**:  Specifies whether the IP Address is provided by a DHCP server or is a Static Address.
- **`MacAddress`**: The MAC address of the NIC
- **`Status`**:  The Interface is functional (Up) or not (Down)
- **`InterfaceType`**:  The type of the Interface. This value can be one of the many possible types of Interfaces: **`Wireless80211`**, **`Tunnel`**, **`FastEthernetFx`** etc.

The **`IPV4Addresses`** property return a simplified list of the IP Addresses associated with the Network Interface. These informations are contained in a **`IpV4AddressInfo`** class, which provides these properties:

- **`IpAddress`**: String representation of the IP Address.
- **`NetMask`**: String representation of the NetMask of the Ip Address.
- **`DefaultGateway`**: String representation of the Default Gateway address.
- **`IsDnsEligible`**: Specifies that the IP Address can appear in a DNS (is routable)

Sample usage:

```
Dim allNicsInfo = NetInterfacesInfo.GetNetworkInterfaces()
For Each nic As NetInterfacesInfo.NetWorkInterfacesInfo In allNicsInfo
    Console.WriteLine($"Description: {nic.Description} Type: {nic.InterfaceType}")
Next

Dim Wireless = allNicsInfo.Where(Function(nic) nic.InterfaceType = NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
```

---

2. **`NetInterfacesInfo.IpV4AddressSimpleList`**

The simplified list of IP Addresses associated with a Network Interface can also be retrieved using this static (shared) method, providing the *Name* (actually, the `Description` property) of a Network Interface.
This method returns a **`List(Of IpV4AddressInfo)`**, a simplified, string only version, of each IP Address (of the specified Network Interface), its NetMask and the associated Default Gateway.

Sample usage:

```
Dim nicInfo = NetInterfacesInfo.IpV4AddressSimpleList("Some NIC Name")

For Each ipV4Addr As NetInterfacesInfo.IpV4AddressInfo In nicInfo
    Console.WriteLine(ipV4Addr.IpAddress)
    Console.WriteLine(ipV4Addr.NetMask)
    Console.WriteLine(ipV4Addr.DefaultGateway)
Next
```

---

Attach the main class to a ComboBox:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim allNicsInfo = NetInterfacesInfo.GetNetworkInterfaces()
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "ConnectionName"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = allNicsInfo
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim cbo = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    If cbo.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return
    Dim nicInfo = DirectCast(cbo.SelectedItem, NetInterfacesInfo.NetWorkInterfacesInfo)
    TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, nicInfo.IPV4Addresses.
                    Select(Function(nic) $"IP Address: {nic.IpAddress} NetMask: {nic.NetMask}"))
    TextBox2.Text = nicInfo.IPV4Addresses.First().DefaultGateway
End Sub
```

---

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class NetInterfacesInfo

    Public Shared Function GetNetworkInterfaces() As List(Of NetWorkInterfacesInfo)
        Dim ifInfo As New List(Of NetWorkInterfacesInfo)()

        ifInfo.AddRange(GetNetworInterfaces().
            Where(Function(nic) nic.NetworkInterfaceType <> NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback AndAlso
                                nic.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4)).
            Select(Function(nic) New NetWorkInterfacesInfo() With {
                .Description = nic.Description,
                .ConnectionName = nic.Name,
                .IsDHCPEnabled = nic.GetIPProperties().GetIPv4Properties().IsDhcpEnabled,
                .DHCPSservers = nic.GetIPProperties().DhcpServerAddresses.ToList(),
                .DnsServers = nic.GetIPProperties().DnsAddresses.ToList(),
                .Gateways = nic.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Select(Function(ipa) ipa.Address).ToList(),
                .InterfaceType = nic.NetworkInterfaceType,
                .IpAddresses = nic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Select(Function(ipa) ipa.Address).ToList(),
                .MacAddress = nic.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes().
                              Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X")).Aggregate(Function(s1, s2) s2 + ":" + s1),
                .Status = nic.OperationalStatus,
                .IPV4Addresses = GetIpV4AddressInfo(nic)
            }))
        Return ifInfo
    End Function

Public Shared Function IpV4AddressSimpleList(nicName As String) As List(Of IpV4AddressInfo)
    Dim nic = GetNetworInterfaceByName(nicName)
    If nic Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Return nic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.
            Where(Function(ipa) ipa.Address.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork).
            Select(Function(ipa) New IpV4AddressInfo() With {
                .IpAddress = ipa.Address?.ToString(),
                .NetMask = ipa.IPv4Mask?.ToString(),
                .IsDnsEligible = ipa.IsDnsEligible,
                .DefaultGateway = nic.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.FirstOrDefault()?.Address?.ToString()
            }).ToList()
End Function

Private Shared Function GetIpV4AddressInfo(nic As NetworkInterface) As List(Of IpV4AddressInfo)
    Return nic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.
            Where(Function(ipa) ipa.Address.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork).
            Select(Function(ipa) New IpV4AddressInfo() With {
                .IpAddress = ipa.Address?.ToString(),
                .NetMask = ipa.IPv4Mask?.ToString(),
                .IsDnsEligible = ipa.IsDnsEligible,
                .DefaultGateway = nic.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.FirstOrDefault()?.Address?.ToString()
            }).ToList()
End Function

    Private Shared Function GetNetworInterfaces() As NetworkInterface()
        Return NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetNetworInterfaceByName(nicName As String) As NetworkInterface
        Return NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(Function(nic) nic.Name = nicName)
    End Function

    Public Class NetWorkInterfacesInfo
        Public Property ConnectionName As String
        Public Property Description As String
        Public Property IPV4Addresses As List(Of IpV4AddressInfo)
        Public Property IpAddresses As List(Of IPAddress)
        Public Property DHCPSservers As List(Of IPAddress)
        Public Property DnsServers As List(Of IPAddress)
        Public Property Gateways As List(Of IPAddress)
        Public Property IsDHCPEnabled As Boolean
        Public Property MacAddress As String
        Public Property Status As OperationalStatus
        Public Property InterfaceType As NetworkInterfaceType
    End Class

    Public Class IpV4AddressInfo
        Public Property IpAddress As String
        Public Property NetMask As String
        Public Property DefaultGateway As String
        Public Property IsDnsEligible As Boolean
    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: So, I ran through your post and implemented it by your example, however it threw an exception that I am nowhere near capable of sussing out. I've taken a screenshot however can't post the image directly so here's a gyazo link. [link](https://gyazo.com/af7b772ae386325578e44085ae98d7c0)

Comment: Yep. The *translation* missed some null checks when converting the addresses to string. I fixed those you reported. There might be other `?` missing here and there. I'll give it a look. Tell me if you find other issues.

Comment: Ok so your adjustments solved the initial problem, however I'm lost as to what name I should be putting for IpV4AddressSimpleList("Some NIC name")

I tried feeding it "Ethernet" (Which works for everything else I've been doing regarding NICs) and it throws up this exception https://gyazo.com/feacf902b104c4597a401728dc8117f5

Thankyou so much for your help so far, I can't express gratitude enough

Comment: Wait to be grateful until we set this up correctly :) `IpV4AddressSimpleList` expects the default description provided by the NIC itself. If you don't alrerady have this description, you can use the first method, `GetNetworkInterfaces()`. which will return all the Interfaces. Following the *sample usage* described, you could write `Dim allNicsInfo = NetInterfacesInfo.GetNetworkInterfaces() Dim nicInfo = NetInterfacesInfo.IpV4AddressSimpleList(allNicsInfo(0).Description)` to get this information on Interface 0.

Comment: But, the first method already returns the simplified list in its `IPV4Addresses` property. The second (simplified) method is intended (in my view), to re-read the same (simplified) values if a different moment, when, for example, you have already added all the descriptions in a ListBox/ComboBox and you want to update the information. So you can just feed the `IpV4AddressSimpleList` the NIC description and update the UI, for example.

Comment: It's working almost perfectly now! However, is it possible to have it function off of connectionName rather than description? Purely to make it more legible to the individuals who will inevitably be using the software once it is complete. I've tried chasing it back, but given you're the one who wrote the function you could most definitely provide a cleaner solution.

Comment: Of course you can, it's just a LINQ query, you can make it return whatever you want, event though is not directly implemented as a method. Anyway, I'll make the change you suggested in the `IpV4AddressSimpleList`.

Comment: There. Now you can pass the Network Connection Name as the argument. Note that you have some NICs without default gateway, as it turns out from the previous error. So the Gateway will be a null string. Be aware of this and prepare to handle a value  `= nothing`

Comment: If it helps, here is the form GUI, the top left combo box is where the user is intended to select their interface, using the simplified names for their sake, ideally I want to be able to just use the combobox.selectedItem to fetch the connection name and feed that into your functions rather than having to do multiple checks to get the right adapter description. Bit mundane, I know, but I'm pretty rusty with VB and keeping things simple helps my brain stay below critical mass.

Comment: See the update, on how to attach the class to a ComboBox (or ListBox or whatever else supports a DataSource).

Comment: Going to go ahead and flag this question as answered, your help was phenomenal, Jimi. I can't thank you enough!